# Eclipse: How to change the list shown in the "switch workspaces" menu?

Tags: eclipse, configuration

After trying a few things out, I ended up in a situation, where I'd like to clean up the workspace list shown in the menu `File > Switch Workspace > ..`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to `Windows > Preferences` Enter text to filter as `Workspaces`.
2. Here, you will see the list of recent ones.
3. You can select and remove the unwanted ones.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that Eclipse has a *Preference* for it:

```
Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces
```

[image: Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces]